# use git to optimize different work flow

Tags: git, bash, automation

git is to track which file has changes. What I want to achieve is that I want to remove all the other files which haven't been changes by me. How is that possible with git?

Comment: Do you mean, for each file, crawl through its entire history and find files for which you are the only person to have created and modified any line in the file? Or do you mean you were the original comitter? or do you want files that havent been touched by you? or what?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all the files in the repo except .git via `rm`. If there is any invisible file or folder in the git root, remove them one by one. Do not use `git rm` here.

   rm -rf *
2. Find all the files you have changed and check them out from the HEAD tree. If you have once renamed a file from NameA to NameB, `git checkout NameA` will return error, which could be just ignored since NameA no longer exists in the HEAD tree already.

   git log --author=yourname --pretty="revert:%h" --name-only | grep -v -E "^revert:|^$" | sort -u | while read line;do git checkout "$line";done
3. Stage the changes and make a commit.

   git add -A;git commit -m 'remove files not changed by me'

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this `git blame --porcelain <file> | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort | uniq -c` which shows you who has touched the current version of the file (note that if someone originally touched a previous version of the file and then someone else later touched those same lines, then this won't detect the original touch-er (hence my question to your original question above)). But assuming that's what you want, you could delete files that have a name other than yours in the above output, and you can iterate recursively over your directory structure doing this.